# SQLite Update date SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, sql-update

SQLite Newbie

I am trying to update a table with a date.

Something like this:

```
Update MyTable Set MyCol=GetDate()
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by "update a table with a date"? Are you trying to set the value of MyCol to the current date for all rows in the table?

Comment: Don't you need a where-clause there? You'll end up changing every single record of the table!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 UPDATE table SET datecol=date('now')
```

This'll set the whole table to the date now.

```
 UPDATE table SET datecol=date('now') WHERE id=666
```

Or if it's a datetime column, datetime('now')

Answer (score 2):

You have a complete reference [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

To update to the current date/time do this:

```
update mytable set mycol=date('now')
```

Comment: Warning to OP: before running this code to test it, please make sure that you understand what it does and that it is what you want to do.

Comment: @Marks is right, you should also add a __WHERE__ clause to affect only the relevant records.

Answer (score 1):

time Update According to below Query 
But One Query How Update Both Date And Time?

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycol=Time('now')
```